# How to make autocomplete show data from another table in Laravel

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, laravel, autocomplete

i have tow table "patient" table and "booking" table , and there is a relationship "One to Many" between them ,i want to set up a search form in index_booking page where user can type a patient_name on it and auto complete show all patient_name from patient table according to WHERE Condition.

this is Booking Model:

```
class Booking extends Eloquent
{

 public function patient()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Patient'); 

    }

    public function user()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 

    }
}
```

this is Patient Model:

```
class Patient extends Eloquent
{
     public function booking()
    {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Booking'); 

    }

     public function user()
    {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User'); 

    }
}
```

and i used this code in index page of booking:

```
{!! Form::text('search_text', null, array('placeholder' => 'Search Text','class' => 'form-control','id'=>'search_text')) !!}
```

i dont know the syntax of code to auto complete, this code code working perfect but to search in booking table not in patient table:

public function autoComplete(Request $request) {
            $query = $request->get('term','');

```
        $bookings=Booking::with(['patient' => function ($query) {
        $query->where('company_id','=' ,Auth::user()->company_id);

       }])->$data=array();
        foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
                $data[]=array('value'=>$booking->patient->patient_name,'id'=>$booking->patient->id);
        }
        if(count($data))
             return $data;
        else
            return ['value'=>'No Result Found','id'=>''];
    }
```

in general this is my BookingController after trying another code for auto complete:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Booking;
use App\Patient;
use App\User;
use Session;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Input;
class BookingController extends Controller
{
   public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
```

/* this code to make normal search box by type patient name and its working grate */

```
    public function index()
    {


$search = \Request::get('search');

$bookings = Booking::whereHas('patient', function ($query) use ($search) {
     $query->where('patient_name', 'like', '%' . $search . '%');
})->where('status','=', null)->whereHas('patient', function ($query){
  $query->where('company_id','=' ,Auth::user()->company_id); 
})->paginate(10);




         return view('booking.index')->withBookings($bookings);
    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
```

/*i tried this code to autocomplete but working */

```
public function autoComplete(Request $request) {
        $query = $request->get('term','');

        $bookings=Booking::whereHas('patient', function ($query){
        $query->where('company_id','=' ,Auth::user()->company_id);

        })->$data=array();
        foreach ($bookings as $booking) {
                $data[]=array('value'=>$booking->patient->patient_name,'id'=>$booking->id);
        }
        if(count($data))
             return $data;
        else
            return ['value'=>'No Result Found','id'=>''];
    }
```

and this is Route:

```
Route::get('autocomplete',array('as'=>'autocomplete','uses'=>'BookingController@index'));
Route::get('searchajax',array('as'=>'searchajax','uses'=>'BookingController@autoComplete'));
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, you want to show autocomplete records from your  DB. Then this  tutorial may help you. 

Its based on typeahead and bloodhound. I used the same in my project. 

https://scotch.io/tutorials/implementing-smart-search-with-laravel-and-typeahead-js

Comment: yes i have successfully made an autocomplete to show data from my database but i want to show this data from another table .

Comment: Any Help Please ??

Comment: When you are getting record to show it in the autocomplete. You can do a join call with your query or if you are using elequoent than you can get your relational data by using "with" like Model::with('relation')->get(); And can filter or return back data in json or to view. 

For more help, please share your code here.